# Loop Code Optimization

Tags: php, for-loop, optimization

How can I optimize the following code ,

I Need to run 3 sets of loops like this:

```
for($i=1;$i<=$count-1;$i++){    
  for($j=$i+1;$j<=$count;$j++){
  // do some query use $i and $j

  }
}
for($i=1;$i<=$count-2;$i++){
   for($j=$i+1;$j<=$count-1;$j++){   
     for($k=$j+1;$k<=$count;$k++){
       // do some query use $i and $j and $k
     }
  }
}
for($i=1;$i<=$count-3;$i++){
   for($j=$i+1;$j<=$count-2;$j++){   
      for($k=$j+1;$k<=$count-1;$k++){
     for($l=$k+1;$l<=$count;$l++){ 
       // do some query use $i and $j and $k and $l
       }
     }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to simplify the code, perhaps to connect the loops together ?

thanks !

Comment: Do you really have to do it that way? Nested for loops are always slow. You probably can even more optimize if you restructure your algorithm.

Comment: `$k1`? *l* comes after *k*. ;-)

Comment: omg, your third loop is like O(n^4)

Comment: Post the `do something`, you might be able to `do something` with fewer loops, but if we don't know what you're doing we can't help.

Comment: But to answer your question: you can only optimize loops if you know what you are doing with them. Only then you can skip some steps or reorganize the iterations.

Comment: What is the query you're executing in each set of loops? It may be feasible to refactor the query to return all the results in one go, rather than accessing the database within every loop.

Comment: Besides the n^4 "problem", is the order of queries important?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Micro-optimization:
Use

```
++$i
```

rather than

```
$i++
```

and equivalent for $j++, $k++ and $l++

But what are you doing in these loops: it's entirely possible that your do some query (database?) could be changed to remove the loops completely... and that would be far more effective than any micro-optimisations

Comment: This is just **pathetic**.  Sorry, but how is this the accepted answer?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it (untested):

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $count - 3; $i++) {
    for($j = $i + 1; $j <= $count; $j++) {
        // i,j query

        if($j > $count - 2) {
            continue;
        }

        for($k = $j + 1; $k <= $count; $k++) {
            // i,j,k query

            if($k > $count - 1) {
                continue;
            }

            for($l = $k + 1; $l <= $count; $l++) {
                // i,j,k,l query
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the queries are no longer in their original order.

As it has been said, there's no way to optimize this further without knowing the queries you are running.

Answer (score 1):

The big problem is that the inner loops are run multiple times. You can get around this by checking `i === 1` and `j === 2` inside the loops and only running the appropriate code if true.

Comment: I did not understand how to implement it, I'd be grateful if you could specify